# Safari on the iPhone & iPad gives colour feedback on touch, I want to stop this

Tags: iphone, ipad, webkit

Clicking on an element which has a Javascript handler makes the element go have a 'grey overlay'. This is normally fine but I'm using event delegation to handle the touchdown events of many child elements. Because of the delegation the 'grey overlay' is appearing over the parent element and looks bad and confusing.

I could attach event handlers to the individual elements to avoid the problem but this would be computationally very wasteful. I'd rather have some webkit css property that I can override to turn it off. I already have visual feedback in my app so the 'grey overlay' is not needed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[-webkit-tap-highlight-color](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html)

> To disable tap highlighting, set the
>   alpha value to 0 (invisible)

Answer (score 2):

$('body').bind('touchstart', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
})

Comment: Not everyone in the world uses jQuery, you know.

Comment: I feel sorry for those people.

Answer (score 0):

For those reading this question, another CSS property which will not only remove the overlay but also prevent the touch device from interacting with the user to assess a tap intention (which delays the timing of the event trigger significantly), is to use the `cursor` property.

```
a.notTappable {
    cursor:default
}
```

Also, in the case the asker described where you have descendants of a parent and you only want the descendants to be tappable and you wish to IGNORE ALL MOUSE EVENTS OF THE PARENT, the following solution will you give you the best performance (by completely disabling the bubbling up to the parent). Read the webkit spec [here](http://www.webkit.org/specs/PointerEventsProperty.html).

```
.parent {
    pointer-events:none;
}
.parent .descendant {
    pointer-events:default;
}
```

I only mention this because the performance difference here is significant.